# npm ERR! Cannot find module 'hawk'

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

I got this error when I create react file:

> C:\Users\ninoos>cd C:\Users\ninoos\Desktop\react-springboot
>
> C:\Users\ninoos\Desktop\react-springboot>npm install -g create-react-app
>   npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>   npm ERR! Cannot find module 'hawk'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\ninoos\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-02-21T20_44_49_047Z-debug.log

[image]

Comment: Per https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7218 can you try uninstall node,npm and reinstalling it and see if it goes away?

Comment: What do you mean by create react file?  Do you already have create-react-app installed?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install node via homebrew? if so

To remove:

```
brew uninstall node; 
# or `brew uninstall --force node` which removes all versions
brew cleanup;
rm -f /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d;
rm -rf ~/.npm;
```

To install:

```
brew install node;
which node # => /usr/local/bin/node
export NODE_PATH='/usr/local/lib/node_modules' # <--- add this ~/.bashrc
```

You can run brew info node for more details regarding your node installs.

You should be able to install create-react-app globally after this.

Comment: i did not install homebrew

Comment: How did you install node?